# Why is my Ubuntu computer slow when a Logitech C920 USB camera is attached?

Tags: usb, performance, webcam

I have a USB Webcam (Logitech C920), which (when attached) sometimes slows down my whole computer to less than 10% of the regular speed.
I'm not only talking about boot times; which could be explained by the BIOS trying to boot from a USB “drive.” Instead the boot devices selection is slowed down significantly. It takes up to half a second to change the entry with the arrow keys, usually I can’t notice *any* delay.

Just waiting and booting into the OS (tried both Windows and Ubuntu) works, but is also so slow, that i unfortunately never managed to get a working shell. As soon as I disconnect the webcam it’s as fast as usual again.

I work in IT, but can’t explain this but I’m curious as to what it could be?

I can’t recognize any patterns when it does this and when not, but I don't change anything in my setup.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB webcam and/or tried the same webcam on a different PC.  The behavior you describe indicates the device is not functional.

Comment: Another idea is to connect the USB cam to a USB hub and then connect the USB hub to the computer. Also, what model computer are you attempting this on?

Comment: I'm also curious what's happening in your system logs while the camera is plugged in. I'd expect to see a large volume of resets or some other issue.